# .htaccess 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration

I have a fairly simple .htaccess, that creates a 500 Internal Server Error.  This is hosted on a private server, so it can't be the hosting company's fault.

```
AllowOverride Indexes
IndexOptions +Indexes +FancyIndexing +FoldersFirst
```

Even reducing it to

```
AllowOverride Indexes
IndexOptions +Indexes
```

doesn't help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Start with an empty file and see if you're still having the same problem it could just be a permission issue. What perms are on the file?

Comment: 755 for permissions seems to work.  Now the options don't do anything: the listing is empty...

Comment: I think the right syntax is `Options +indexes`. Also AllowOverride not allowed in htaccess.

Comment: Okay, my .htaccess now contains `Options +Indexes` and `IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +FoldersFirst`.  It now gives a 500 internal server error.

Comment: If it is hosted on a VPS, then do you have error logging enabled and what does the Apache error log report on this error?

Comment: It's not a VPS just a private server.  However, logging is enabled, and theoretically I could get at the error logs, but I don't have access.  I'll see what I can do.